# Identify gaps in N dimensional data set

Tags: c#, math

We have an interesting problem we need to resolve here, we're using C# .NET 4.0 but the language should be irrelevant as it's a mathematical problem.

**Problem**: we need to identify gaps in N dimensional data set and report exactly where those gaps are back to the user.

For example, let's assume we're working with 3-D, so we have this object `Quote` with 6 properties: `TermFrom, TermTo, AgeFrom, AgetTo, AmountFrom, AmountTo` and boundaries we need to cover: `MinTerm = 0, MaxTerm = 5, MinAge = 0, MaxAge = 5, MinAmount = 0, MaxAmount = 5`. Assuming all minimums are `0` and maximums are `5` just to simplify the example, albeit they could be different. So, the data we need to check for gaps in is the following data set:

```
Quote[] {
  {  TermFrom=0, TermTo=3, AgeFrom=0, AgetTo=4, AmountFrom=0, AmountTo=2  },
  {  TermFrom=4, TermTo=5, AgeFrom=0, AgetTo=5, AmountFrom=3, AmountTo=5  }
```

This dataset contains gaps for combinations: `{ Term: 0-5, Age: 4-5, Amount: 0-2 } and { Term: 0-3, Age: 0-5, Amount: 2-5 }, { Term: 4-5, Age: 0-5, Amount: 0-2 }` (i think)

i.e. if you imagine a cube and the datasets are parts of this cube, to calculated total volume of all datasets must be equal to the cube's volume. And we need to identify where the gaps are in this cube if its volume isn't full.

All of this is required with more dimensions: 4 and 5, but it's a lot harder to visualise. I was hoping there is some sort of mathematical solution to this problem, which we could translate to c# code.

Answer (score 1):

Use a k-d tree, it is meant precisely to partition space for these sorts of applications.